# Как правильно сделать цикл?

Tags: python, python-3.x, циклы, формулы

Зарплата сотрудника в первый день 1 копейка, во второй 2, в третий 4, в пятый 8 и тд. Необходимо запросить у пользователя кол-во отработанных дней? вывести на экран ЗП за каждый день + вывести итоговую ЗП за все дни и сделать так, чтобы она выводилась в рублях, а не в копейках. Использовать можно только for-while, if-else.

```
days = int(input('Количество отработанных дней: '))
total = 0
for money_per_day in range(1, days + 1):
    first_day = 
    next_days = first_day * 2
```

Понимаю, что нужно указать "умножай ЗП каждого предыдущего дня на 2" но как это написать в цикле не понимаю

Рабочий вариант

```
days = int(input('Количество отработанных дней: '))
first_day = 1
for money_per_day in range(1, days + 1):
    print(f'{money_per_day} день - ты заработал {first_day / 100} руб')
    first_day = first_day * 2
print(f'{days} день - суммарно ты заработал {first_day / 100 - 0.01} руб')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### UPD

```
days = int(input('Количество отработанных дней: '))
first_day = 1
for money_per_day in range(1, days):
    print(f'{money_per_day} день - ты заработал {first_day / 100} руб')
    first_day = first_day * 2
print(f'{days} день - суммарно ты заработал {first_day / 100} руб')
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Да вариант хороший! Но при вводе любого кол-ва дней вылазит лишняя копейка, например при вводе 1 отраб день на выходе получаем: 
"Сегодня ты заработал 0.01 руб
За 1 дней ты заработал 0.02 руб"
А в обоих вариантах должно быть 0,01 тк проработал он всего 1 день.
Если ввести 2 отработанных дня, то будет - За 2 дней ты заработал 0.04 руб, а должно быть 0,03 (0,01 за первый день и 0,02 за второй) и тд.

Comment: в последнюю строку нужно добавить: print(f'За все дни ты заработал {(first_day / 100) - 0.01} руб') тогда лишняя копейка уйдет.
Спасибо! Ваше решение помогло разобраться!

Comment: @VetDoctor, немного изменил свой код, посмотри, может в таком виде больше подойдет

Comment: Не так не учитывается 1 день, до этого прям идеальный практически был, там всего 1 правку надо было сделать и все супер, добавил рабочий код выше, где вопрос был

Comment: @VetDoctor, первый день тоже включает )) я правку внес не только в последней строке, а еще и вот тут `range(1, days + 1)` заменил на `range(1, days)`? под кодом фото с результатом выполнения )) ну, либо можешь оставить свой вариант, если он вполне устраивает ))

Comment: Вот в том скрине что вы скинули у вас 9 дней, а 10 строка это уже общая сумма, хотя должно быть 10 дней, а сумма уже в 11 строке

Comment: первый то день включает, да, но не включает последний на данном скрине 10 день не пошел в учет оьщей суммы тк нет приписки range (1, days + 1)

Comment: просто попробуйте написать например что челик работает 2 дня и на выходе получите: 1) за первый день ты заработал .... 2) Суммарно ты заработал... и все, а должно же быть 3 строки: 1 день, второй день и сумма итоговая

Comment: перечитал ваш вопрос, да, ваш вариант более точно покрывает запрос

Answer (score 0):

Зарплата предыдущего дня это `next_days`. Умножить на два это `*2`. Вот именно так и написать. Почти написано уже, кстати.

Инициализировать `first_day` нужно перед циклом.